# firewall-cmd forward rules for interface with multiple IPs?

Tags: linux, firewall

I'm looking for a way with firewall-cmd or another command to do the following.

An incoming public interface has multiple ip addresses bound to it. How can I forward ports only for one of the IP addresses?

```
bond0 - public:
 192.168.1.100 local machine SSHD bound here.
 192.168.1.200  --->  forward  SSH, HTTPS  to  192.168.1.53 vm bridge on machine
```

I can use the `--forward-port` when I forward all incoming traffic on a given port, however I would like to do this only for traffic destined to one target IP.

Routing all traffic destined for .200 to the .53 vm would be the alternative,  not sure how to accomplish that either.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ firewall-cmd --zone=external \
    --add-forward-port=port=80:addr=172.16.1.1:proto=tcp:toport=80:toaddr=192.168.0.2
```

#### References

- [firewalld and iptables - port forwarding works in iptables only](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=293541)

### Using "Rich Language" rule

Forward IPv6 packets received from 1:2:3:4:6:: on port 4011 with protocol TCP to 1::2:3:4:7 on port 4012:

```
rule family="ipv6" source address="1:2:3:4:6::" forward-port to-addr="1::2:3:4:7" to-port="4012" protocol="tcp" port="4011"
```

[4.5.3.7.4.5. Using the Rich Rule Log Command Example 5](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html#sec-Configuring_firewalld)

Comment: I wonder if this is due to an update, but the first half of this answer is completely wrong - neither does an `addr` flag exist for `firewall-cmd --add-forward-port`, nor does the linked post have anything to do with the question, nor does the linked post cover the supposed `addr` parameter. The second part does not address the question at all either.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this through a search for the same thing, and ended up working out the solution myself: it is not possible at all with `--forward-port`, you need a rich rule for that. While the original poster is long gone, hopefully this will be helpful for further searchers like me:

```bash
sudo firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 destination address="192.168.1.200" forward-port port="1-65535" protocol="tcp" to-addr="192.168.1.53"'
sudo firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 destination address="192.168.1.200" forward-port port="1-65535" protocol="udp" to-addr="192.168.1.53"'
```

I've never had a cause to forward a range of ports nor to forward to a different IP, so the latter part might not be exactly correct, but the relevant part (for the initial question) is the `destination address` part of the rich rule, which will limit it to connection attempts to that IP.